# Scaling SVG loaded from the web in React Native?

Tags: react-native, svg

I'm having some trouble getting svgs loaded from an API to work, some svgs seem to have a viewbox property some don't. Some svgs load correctly and fill the container, others are tiny, and others don't display at all (possibly too large).

The JSON data can be found here: https://snapsite.co/output.json each item contains an svg icon.

Here is how I'm currently displaying the svg:

```
<SvgCssUri
  height="100%"
  width="100%"
  uri={image}
/>
```

Here is how it looks
[image: Here's what it looks like]

Comment: I suspect that you need to address your problem with the icon supplier as the icons with `width` and `height` defined and no `viewbox` that cannot be auto resized. I checked a few and icon 22 works fine (no W/H, with VB), icon 23 (W/H defined, no VB) however does not. I used [JSONHero](https://jsonhero.io/j/Ei53ApP9jsv8) for that... (give it time to load your JSON file). Or edit the icon files yourself, but that's not the way to go.

Comment: I managed to solve my issue with a script (Downloaded all the icons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by modifying all the svgs using the following script I cobbled together.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

// Get list of icons from the icons directory
const icons = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "icons"));

const modifySvg = (filepath) => {
  // Load the SVG file
  let svg = fs.readFileSync(filepath, "utf8");

  // Check if svg has viewbox
  const hasViewBox = svg.includes("viewBox");
  if (!hasViewBox) {
    console.log("No viewBox found");
    // Check if width and height are set
    const hasWidth = svg.includes("width");
    const hasHeight = svg.includes("height");
    if (!hasWidth || !hasHeight) {
      console.log("No width or height found");
    } else {
      console.log("Width and height found");
      console.log("Adding viewBox");

      // Get width property
      const widthStr = svg.match(/width="([^"]*)"/)[0];
      const width = widthStr.replace(/"/g, "").replace("width=", "");
      // Get height property
      const heightStr = svg.match(/height="([^"]*)"/)[0];
      const height = heightStr.replace(/"/g, "").replace("height=", "");
      console.log({ width, height });
      // Add viewBox to end of svg tag
      const viewBox = `viewBox="0 0 ${width} ${height}"`;
      svg = svg.replace(/<svg/, `<svg ${viewBox}`);
      // Make width and height are 100%
      svg = svg.replace(/width="[^"]*"/, `width="100%"`);
      svg = svg.replace(/height="[^"]*"/, `height="100%"`);
      // Write the file
      fs.writeFileSync(filepath, svg);
      console.log(`Saved ${filepath}`);
    }
  }
};

//Loop icons
icons.forEach((icon) => {
  // Get file path
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "icons", icon);
  // Modify svg
  modifySvg(filePath);
});
```

Hope this helps someone!